# Using str_replace to replace variable character

Tags: php, string

Basically I am trying to do an str_replace with "?cat=(insert number here)"

```
$queryString2 = str_replace("cat=(insert number here)", "cat=4", $queryString);
```

Is there a way this can be accomplished? Str_replace + one character because the value im searching for could be anything.

```
?cat=7
?cat=3
?cat=4
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A more reliable way of handling query strings would be to actually parse them.

```
// If your original query string was just the data in $_GET, clone $_GET:
$new_query = $_GET;
// Otherwise, parse the original query string using parse_str:
parse_str($original_query_string, $new_query);
// Then, set the new cat value, and build a new query string.
$new_query['cat'] = 4;
$new_query_string = http_build_query($new_query);
```

The technique you originally describe is the job of a regular expression :)

```
$queryString2 = preg_replace('/cat=[0-9]+/', 'cat=4', $queryString);
```

The regular expression `cat=[0-9]+` matches the string `cat=` followed by one or more (`+`) digits (`[0-9]`). [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace) replaces all matches of the regular expression (argument 1) found in the original string (argument 3) with the replacement string (argument 2) and returns the result.

Note that this will also replace `dog_and_cat=1` with `dog_and_cat=4`. [borkweb's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4572649/using-str-replace-to-replace-variable-character/4572663#4572663) is a more complex regex, but handles that edge case if it could arise (e.g. this is a query string provided by the user).

I prefer the actual query parsing, but the regular expression solution should ideally work just as well, assuming no edge cases.

Comment: I think "cat" stands for "category" here :P

Comment: @BoltClock: oh, and are you gonna try and tell me that `preg` doesn't stand for a string being pregnant? D:

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you can use [preg_replace](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
$queryString2 = preg_replace('/([&?])cat=[0-9]+/', '\1cat=4', $queryString);
```

That regex will make sure you only grab the "cat" query string.  The pieces are as follows:

```
([&?])  # match either and ampersand or question mark
cat=    # match "cat="
[0-9]+  # match 1 or more digits.
```

The `\1` in the second parameter inserts into the replace string whatever was captured in the parens from the first parameter.

However, using the `parse_str` [example that Matchu gave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4572649/using-str-replace-to-replace-variable-character/4572664#4572664) may be a bit more foolproof with only a little bit of overhead.

Comment: You probably should use `preg_replace('/(?<=[?&])cat=[0-9]+/', 'cat=4', $queryString)` instead if you use a regex solution. The ?/& should be ensured with a lookbehing positiv assertion ;)